# Set jquery select list option from form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, asp-classic

I am having difficulty in setting an option as 'selected' once a form has been submitted. On submitting the form I am able to retrieve the submitted value however am not able to keep the 'state of the form' (yes..easily done in .net however I was brought up on classic ASP and never moved on!).

My ajax & jquery skills are quite limited and I have been searching for a similar example for some time. I can select the option value in the Buy select list however I am unable to set the option value in the Rent list as it is rendered by ajax.

Any help appreciated....Harj

My code below

```
<%
strDept = request("strDept")
strPrice = request("price")

if strDept = "Rent" then
  strRentSelected = " selected "
  strBuySelected = ""
else
  strRentSelected = ""
  strBuySelected = " selected "
end if
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
      $(function(){
        $("#dept").change(function() {
          $('select[name="price"]').removeAttr("name").hide();
          $("#" + $(this).val()).show().attr("name", "price");
        });
      });
    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="main.asp" method="post">
      <select id="dept" name="strDept">
        <option value="Buy" <%=strBuySelected %>>Buy</option>
        <option value="Rent" <%=strRentSelected %>>Rent</option>
      </select>
      <select id="Buy" name="price" class="price">
        <option value="5000">5,000</option>
        <option value="25000">25,000</option>
        <option value="50000">50,000</option>
        <option value="100000">100,000</option>
        <option value="150000">150,000</option>
        <option value="200000">200,000</option>
        <option value="250000">250,000</option>
        <option value="500000">500,000</option>
        <option value="1000000">1,000,000</option>
      </select>
      <select id="Rent" style="display:none" class="price">
        <option value="0">0 pcm</option>
        <option value="200">200 pcm</option>
        <option value="300">300 pcm</option>
        <option value="400">400 pcm</option>
        <option value="500">500 pcm</option>
        <option value="600">600 pcm</option>
        <option value="700">700 pcm</option>
        <option value="1000">1000 pcm</option>
        <option value="5000">5000 pcm</option> 
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="Submit" name="strAction" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your Problem? isn't the dept select box entry selected? your code Looks ok...

Comment: You pointing back to the same page when you submit? Is the form action `main.asp` this page? Tend to stick to `action=""` on the form when calling itself for this very reason.

Comment: I'm not sure how you even think this is [tag:ajax]? What you are doing (from what I can determine) is a server post back to itself then setting the selected value via server-side processing. The only client-side action is to hide the `#price` dropdown when you trigger the change event in the `#dept` dropdown, not sure why you're even doing that? What are you actually trying to do? Are you wanting to trigger an ajax post when the `#dept` dropdown changes and affect the `#price` dropdown in some way?